# PHP MySQL affected_rows = -1 after SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to solve my problem by reading, but i could not find a solution.
I am searching in my database for a id. The $stmt->affected_rows() is always -1.
I don't know what I am doing wrong here...

```
$uuid = '76561198036258382';
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT steamid, personaname FROM cs_user 
WHERE steamid = ?"))) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $uuid)) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){
echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
print_r($stmt);
```

The good news: I got no error from mysqli.
The bad news: The output from print_r is:

```
mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => -1
    [insert_id] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 1
    [field_count] => 2
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)
```

But the id I was searching for is in my DB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the problem .. you are searching and that doesn't affect any row in the database

Comment: Its `select` query, select query will not affect any record in table. If its update query then it will show the count.

Comment: select query count will get from `num_rows`  and insert,update query count will get from `affected rows`

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** `select` query `count` of `rows`  will get from `num_rows` .

**2nd :** `Insert,update,delete` `affected row` `count` will get from `affected_rows`

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate more on the answer.

queries to pull a count or data using num_rows, however they must be called from a result of the query using a variable.
example:

```
$query = $cnx->query("select * from users where users.username = '" . $user['username'] . "'");

$query->num_rows;
```

but for manipulation of data using affected_rows it can be called directly from the connection variable itself.

```
$cnx->query("UPDATE users SET " . $query . " WHERE users.id = " . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . ";")

$cnx->affected_rows
```